# Access model properties in Django Admin templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have Django 2.0.3 on Python 3.5.3. I search for simple way to small improve my standard Django Admin dashboard (main page of Django Admin).

Here is my template for Admin main page `./templates/admin/index.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/dashboard.css" %}"/>{% endblock %}

{% block coltype %}colMS{% endblock %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} dashboard{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div id="content-main">

    {% if app_list %}
      {% for app in app_list %}
        <div class="app-{{ app.app_label }} module">
          <table>
            <caption>
              <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section"
                 title="{% blocktrans with name=app.name %}Models in the {{ name }} application{% endblocktrans %}">{{ app.name }}</a>
            </caption>
            {% for model in app.models %}
              <tr class="model-{{ model.object_name|lower }}">
                {% if model.admin_url %}
                  <th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></th>
                {% else %}
                  <th scope="row">{{ model.name }}</th>
                {% endif %}

                {% if model.add_url and request.user.is_superuser %}
                  <td><a href="{{ model.add_url }}" class="addlink">{% trans 'Add' %}</a></td>
                {% else %}
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                {% endif %}

                {% if model.admin_url and request.user.is_superuser %}
                  <td><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}" class="changelink">{% trans 'Change' %}</a></td>
                {% else %}
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                {% endif %}
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <p>{% trans "You don't have permission to edit anything." %}</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I delete sidebar block, because I never use it. And it looks like:

[image]

I want to add to each model link count of objects. For example, `Cities (23)`, `Citizenships (102)` and similar for all models in list. I try to add function with `@property` decorator in `./app/models.py`, but it's not working:

```
class APIConfig(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def with_active_status(self):
        return self.objects.filter(is_active=True).count()
    ...
```

I call this property in Admin template, like `{{ model.with_active_status }}` and it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be a property. You don't have an instance of the model to call it on. In any case, if you did have an instance it still wouldn't work, as model managers - `objects` - can only be accessed from the class, not the instance.

You should make it a classmethod:

```
@classmethod
def with_active_status(cls):
    return cls.objects.filter(is_active=True).count()
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. But `@classmethod` is still not access him self on Django Admin templates. How to do it in my case?